# VBAでpythonを動かしたときのpermissionErrorの解決方法

Tags: python, python3, vba

VBAでpythonのプログラムを動かす際にタイトルのエラーが出ます。
エラー内容はPermissionError : Permission denied:'excelのファイル名.xlsm'
よろしくお願いいたします。

VBAのコードはこちらです。

```
Sub SampleCall()
    RunPython ("import auto_py;auto_py.textdownload()")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Excelのファイルが起動されている場合、そのファイルは、他のアプリケーションからは読み取りも書き込みも禁止になります。`auto_py`の中で起動中のExcelのファイルにアクセスしているとそのエラーが発生します。

一般的には、そのExcelのファイルを閉じてから実行すればいいのですが、もし、そのExcelのファイルがその`VBA`があるファイルであれば閉じることができないので、処理の前後にクリップボード等にデータを保存することで回避するようにします。

クリップボードを使う場合には、Pandasを使うと楽です。VBA側を以下のようにして

```
Sub SampleCall()
    Range("A1:E10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    RunPython ("import auto_py;auto_py.textdownload()")
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Python側は、次のように簡単に書くことができます。必要に応じて`header`等のオプションを設定してください。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
#処理
df.to_clipboard()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。pythonのプログラム実行中にvbaのコードを記入してあるシートのセル内容をクリップボードに保存し回避するということで大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: クリップボードに保存が一番簡単です。